# Difference between LINQ Queries & Lambda expression

Tags: linq, lambda

Why to use lambda expression when we have LINQ queries just to shorten the length of code , increase the speed of development or is there any other reason which can only be achieved by Lambda expression & not by LINQ queries.

Comment: Usually one of the two is more succinct, depending on the problem - you should use both as appropriate

Comment: @BrokenGlass: It would definitely be pretty rare for them to be *exactly the same* in length :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Query expressions only cover a small subset of the LINQ operators, and are only applicable when you have the actual expression involved to hand, rather than (say) having a `Func<T, bool>` to act as the predicate, in which case things become ugly. So instead of writing:

```
Func<Foo, bool> predicate = ...; // Get predicate from somewhere
var query = from x in collection
            where predicate(x)
            select x;
```

I'd much rather write:

```
Func<Foo, bool> predicate = ...; // Get predicate from somewhere
var query = collection.Where(predicate);
```

There are various other cases where using non-query expression syntax is simpler, particularly if your query only uses a single operator.

Query expressions are effectively translated into non-query expressions, so anything you can do in query expressions *can* be expressed in non-query expressions. Use query expressions where they make the code simpler and more readable; don't use them where they don't.

I have more information about how query expressions work in a [blog post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work.aspx) that you may be interested in.

Comment: +1 I think I invariably use then together when I write a Query Expression

Answer (score 3):

> any other reason which can only be achieved by Lambda expression & not by LINQ queries.

There are some LINQ extension methods which do not have counterparts in [LINQ query expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx), and will require the use of Lambda Expressions.  A good example is [Enumerable.ToLookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup.aspx) - if you want to create an ILookup, you need to use lambdas to generate this.