# Which is higher in Abstraction Level Linq or Lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net

I always prefer lambda expression to perform operations on collection. But i can achieve same thing with LINQ which is simpler than Lambda expression. but, I am still confused a bit about which comes at top in Abstraction Level & why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391370/is-it-linq-or-lambda/7391389#7391389 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327897/difference-between-linq-queries-lambda-expression/5327982#5327982
Use LINQ queries where it makes the code simpler and more readable; don't use them where they don't. The compiler will treat both the same as lambda expressions.

Comment: You should use whatever is more convenient for you, not whatever has higher abstraction level (whatever it means).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suspect by "LINQ" you mean "query expressions":

```
var query = from x in y
            where x.Foo
            select x.Bar
```

And I suspect by "lambda expression" you mean calling the extension methods directly:

```
var query = y.Where(x => x.Foo)
             .Select(x => x.Bar);
```

Both of these are *really* LINQ...

Query expressions are at a *slightly* higher abstraction level I guess, and that there's more work required to get down to the real operations... but not terribly significantly, given that the conversion process is fairly mechanical.

Comment: +1 Because I couldn't comprehend the question... But the response was very clear :-) :-)

Comment: +1 for bringing it up that both are called LINQ. Its sad that many people don't understand this.

Comment: @Hasan: It's not so much that both are *called* LINQ - it's that both approaches are *part* of LINQ. You're using LINQ either way, and indeed the same generated code.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Yes I meant the same thing. I'm not a native english speaker :)

Answer (score 3):

LINQ expressions are translated by the compiler into the corresponding extension methods. Lambda expressions are part of the BCL, whereas LINQ syntax is just syntactic sugar which gets translated by the compiler, it's not part of the emitted IL.

Comment: I don't under stand how list.Select(.. is not LINQ?

Comment: A nitpick: Aren't lambda expressions just compiler sugar too? They'll either be translated into anonymous methods or expression trees; they don't exist as "lambda expressions" in the emitted IL.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your question is actually about the difference between Linq in query syntax (from car in carList select car.Brand) and method syntax (carList.Select(car => car.Brand))?
In that case, it is easily answered: Linq's query syntax is only syntactic sugar, and will be translated into method calls. As such, they are pretty much identical as far as abstraction level goes. Query syntax just looks more comprehensible to the average human.

Menno