# How do I split the string into a long() type array in Excel VBA?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Let's say I have something like `"1-34-52"`, I want to split them into an array, however, while Test1 works, it gives me an `String()` type array. How do I put the numbers in `"1-34-52"` into a `Long()` type array? Can I `redim` type of an array in VBA?

```
Sub Test1()
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Split("1-34-52", "-")
    Debug.Print TypeName(arr), TypeName(arr(0))
End Sub

Sub Test2()
    Dim arr() As Long
    arr = Split("1-34-52") 'You get type mismatch error
End Sub
```

Comment: First issue I see is you are not putting a delimiter in your split statement, change it to `Split("1-34-52", "-")`. Secondly, I would just use CLng when I use the element: `TypeName(CLng(arr(0)))`

Comment: Here's a post where someone had a similar situation with integers...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121595/convert-saved-string-of-numbers-into-an-array-of-integers

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

You can `Redim` an array of `Variants`.  Since Variants can hold integer values, there is no problem:

```
Sub dural()
    ary = Split("1-34-52", "-")
    ReDim lary(0 To UBound(ary))
    For i = 0 To UBound(ary)
        lary(i) = CLng(ary(i))
    Next i
End Sub
```

Note:

```
Sub dural()
    ary = Split("1-34-52", "-")
    Dim lary() As Long
    ReDim lary(0 To UBound(ary))
    For i = 0 To UBound(ary)
        lary(i) = CLng(ary(i))
    Next i
End Sub
```

will also work.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the array and populate a new one:

```
Sub Test1()
    Dim arr As Variant, LongArr() As Long, X As Long
    arr = Split("1-34-52", "-")
    ReDim LongArr(UBound(arr))
    For X = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        LongArr(X) = CLng(arr(X))
    Next
    Debug.Print TypeName(arr), TypeName(arr(0))
    Debug.Print TypeName(LongArr), TypeName(LongArr(0))
End Sub
```